# connecting combobox (c#) with MS-Access table headers

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have an MS Access Database. This contains 4 tables with names `London`, `Lovrpool`, `Manchaster`, `Norwich`.

In C# Windows Forms I want to make a combobox and I want to connect that combo with the tables not with the rows in table.

So I want to chose from combo for example London and then put:

```
        if (afInput.Text != "" && pnInput.Text != "") 
        {
            try
            {
                if (comboBox1.SelectedText - place where I want to put some code that I don't know)
                {
                    cnn.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into London name=" +name.text;
                    cnn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: you mean, List the table names in combobox and when user select table, you want to display all rows.

Comment: I want to give user option to chose the table and after he chose from ombo all data that he provides will goes to the right table.

Comment: Do these four tables all have the same structure? If so, your database design is almost certainly flawed.